# How to include the elasticsearch javascript library in aurelia?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, aurelia

Coming from the angular world, there was a lot to learn in aurelia. No problem, but now I'm stuck. The issue is how to include `elasticsearch.js` in my aurelia-app.
Does someone have tips for me how to do that? Or a pointer for further reading?

My research:

- aurelia documentation on [including libraries](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/6): contains good examples but no solution for the elasticsearch library
- stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796065/importing-elasticsearch-into-aurelia): I can't reproduce the solution in my project

The project:

- using aurelia cli
- elasticsearch installed with npm
- added the following to aurelia.json

  ```
  {
      "name": "elasticsearch",
      "path": "../node_modules/elasticsearch/src",
      "main": "elasticsearch"
  }
  ```

The problem:

- running `au run --watch` results in an error

  ```
  { uid: 10,
    name: 'writeBundles',
    branch: false,
    error: 
     { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/xxxxxxxx/dev/aurelia_testrun/au-basic/src/path.js'
  ```
- it seems that something is looking for files - like `path.js` - in the app's source directory. is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some googling, it looks like there is a separate package for use in the browser, called 'elasticsearch-browser'. It can be installed via npm, then including it in your `aurelia.json` file is as simple as adding `"elasticsearch-browser"` to the dependency list for your `vendor-bundle.js` file.

I'm able to import and use it like this:

```
import elasticSearch from 'elasticsearch-browser';

console.log("elasticsearch", elasticsearch.Client());
```

It looks like this in the log:

[image]